# Draw a graph in WFA

Tags: c#, winforms, graph

Is there any library or framework that allow to draw a graph in WinForm Application?
Graph like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28discrete_mathematics%29.

ZedGraph allow me to draw a charts but not Graph like Tree.

I may use TreeView, but is there other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/).